# show that $O^{p}(G)$ will generate with all $q$-sylow subgroups of $G$ .

Tags: finite-groups

suppose that $G$ is finite group and $p$ is a prime number,then show that $O^{p}(G)$ will generate with all $q$-sylow subgroups of $G$ where $q$ is arbitrary prime number and  $q\neq p$ .

($O^{p}(G)$ is intersection of all normal subgroups of $G$ where its correspondence quotient group is $p$-group)

any hint or idea or any references to study will be great,thanks.